# How to keep the robot level in motion

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I want to get my Universal Robot model keep level in the simulation in Moveit which means  the rotation of X axis and Y axis of the  robot's end-effector will not be changed and the the rotation of Z axis can be controlled by the planner. My code is listed as followed

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_interface_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;  
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();


  /* This sleep is ONLY to allow Rviz to come up */
  sleep(20.0);
  
  // BEGIN_TUTORIAL
  // 
  // Setup
  // ^^^^^
  // 
  // The :move_group_interface:`MoveGroup` class can be easily 
  // setup using just the name
  // of the group you would like to control and plan for.
  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");

  // We will use the :planning_scene_interface:`PlanningSceneInterface`
  // class to deal directly with the world.
  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;  

  // (Optional) Create a publisher for visualizing plans in Rviz.


     ros::Publisher display_publisher = node_handle.advertise<moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory>("/move_group/display_planned_path", 1, true);
      moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory display_trajectory;

  // Getting Basic Information
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //
  // We can print the name of the reference frame for this robot.
  ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", group.getPlanningFrame().c_str());
  
  // We can also print the name of the end-effector link for this group.
  ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", group.getEndEffectorLink().c_str());

  // Planning to a Pose goal
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // We can plan a motion for this group to a desired pose for the 
  // end-effector.
  robot_state::RobotState start_state(*group.getCurrentState());
  geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose = group.getCurrentPose().pose;
  //geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose2;



  group.setStartState(start_state);
  
  
  moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint ocm;  
  ocm.link_name = "tt_base_link";  
  ocm.header.frame_id = "base_link";
   ocm.orientation.x = 0.003;
  ocm.orientation.y = 0.002;
  //ocm.orientation.z = 0.101;
  //ocm.orientation.w = 0.949;
  //ocm.orientation.z = 0;
    ocm.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
    ocm.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
    ocm.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
  ocm.weight = 1.0;




// Now, set it as the path constraint for the group.
  moveit_msgs::Constraints test_constraints;
  test_constraints.orientation_constraints.push_back(ocm);  
  group.setPathConstraints(test_constraints);

  std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints;
  geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1;
   //ocm.orientation.x = 0;
  //ocm.orientation.y = 0;

 // ocm.orientation.x = 0.003;
  //ocm.orientation.y = 0.002;
  //ocm.orientation.z = 0.101;
 // ocm.orientation.w = 0.949;
target_pose1.position.x = 0.53;
target_pose1.position.y = 0.24;
  target_pose1.position.z = 0.81;
  waypoints.push_back(target_pose1);


   moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
  double fraction = group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, 0.005, 0.0, trajectory);
  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;
  bool success = group.plan(my_plan);
  // Now we will plan to the earlier pose target from the new 
  // start state that we have just created.
  group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);
  success = group.plan(my_plan);

  ROS_INFO("Visualizing plan 3 (constraints) %s",success?"":"FAILED");
  /* Sleep to give Rviz time to visualize the plan. */
  sleep(10.0);

  // When done with the path constraint be sure to clear it.
  group.clearPathConstraints();



  ros::shutdown();  
  return 0;
}
```

So could you check the code and tell me about the mistakes?

---

Edit: @v4hn
Thanks for your answer. I have used the `computeCartesianPath` and `setPathConstraints`to constraint the orientation and let the robot move to a point `next_pose`. And the robot's orientation x,y,z,w did not changed in the process of moving. But my target is that pitch angle and roll angle of the end effector equaling 0 to keep it level and the yaw angle can be any value that is planned by Moveit and now these three angles are all equaling 0 (yaw angle did not change). So could you tell me about the problem and my codes are listed.

```
moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint ocm;

    ocm.link_name = "tool0";
    ocm.header.frame_id = "base_link";
  
   
    ocm.orientation.w = 0.556;
    ocm.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.0;
    ocm.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.0;
    ocm.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
    ocm.weight = 1.0;
    moveit_msgs::Constraints test_constraints;
    test_constraints.orientation_constraints.push_back(ocm);
    group_r.setPathConstraints(test_constraints);



    geometry_msgs::Pose next_pose = start_pose;
  
        std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints;
        next_pose.position.x=0.626;
    next_pose.position.y=0.129;
    next_pose.position.z=0.545;
    //next_pose.orientation.x = 0.002;
    //next_pose.orientation.y = 0.00045;
    //next_pose.orientation.z = 0.830;
    //next_pose.orientation.w = 0.556;
        //next_pose.position.y += 0.5;
    //next_pose.position.z += 0.3;
        //next_pose.orientation.w = 0.557;
        waypoints.push_back(next_pose);  // up and out

        moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
        double fraction = group_r.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, 0.005, 0.0, trajectory);

        /* Sleep to give Rviz time to visualize the plan. */
        sleep(5.0);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273122/how-to-keep-the-robot-level-in-motion/) by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-17**:
what's the specific problem you're running into?

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-10-17**:
When the robot is moving from point A to point B, how can i keep the end effector level(constrainting the pitch angle and roll angle of the end effector equaling 0 and the yaw angle can be any value that is planned by Moveit)?

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-10-17**:
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you know your trajectory can be executed by linear interpolation in work space, `computeCartesianPath` is the most straight-forward.

If that doesn't work, `setPathConstraints` is the right way to go here and should work.
For some kinematics/solvers you might see invalid trajectories resulting from planning.
In that case have a look at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/541 for a workaround.
A Constraint approximation database can heavily reduce planning time here.
Keep an eye at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/638 for a (hopefully) upcoming tutorial.

**Edit:** The tutorial is now online [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/constraints_approximation_database.html).

---

**Edit in reply to edit:**

`setPathConstraints` only works well with `plan` and `move`, but not with `computeCartesianPath`.
The latter "only" interpolates the end-effector pose in workspace - this includes the 3d rotation.
The feasible trajectory is already fully defined in workspace.
So your relaxed constraint does not give you more state space to exploit.

If you want general trajectories that satisfy the constraint, use `setPathConstraints` together with `plan`/`move`.

If you know your trajectory in advance **up to the yaw angle**, have a look at the [descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes) project.
According to the authors, this only works well with analytical IK solvers though.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-10-23**:
Hi, i just want to try to use the "Constraint approximation database " in [link text](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/541/commits/8902a44c1e3c57b90693d4975dadaae490e495ce#diff-e963ab530330db5e6a078de25e70f208) that you recommended and i cannot find the file,

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-10-23**:
moveit_planners/ompl/ompl_interface/src/ompl_interface.cpp in my ROS. Have i missed to install some package?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-11-29**:
To give a late update to this: There is now a tutorial online in http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/constraints_approximation_database.html

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-11-29**:
@v4hn Thank you for your reply. I have used the `Trac-IK` and `setPathConstraints and the end-effector has been kept horizontal to the ground. But it  still has some joint jumping during the process. [Please check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GAVLup7PWE).So Constraint Database will solve the p?